# WU app XAML binding to Button grid from custom collection

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-10-universal

I'm quite new to XAML trying to make grid with Toggle buttons
Something like this:

```
<GridView ItemSource="{Binding ButtonCollection}">
  <GridView.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
     <ToggleButton Content="{Binding Label}" IsEnabled="{Binding BEnabled}" IsChecked="{Binding BChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
  <DataTemplate>
 </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

I have

```
ObservableCollection<ButtonClass> ButtonCollection
```

also class for buttons

```
class ButtonClass
{
 public string Label {get; set;}
 public bool BEnabled {get; set:}
 public bool BChecked {get;set;}
}
```

binding works when page loads buttons are displayed from ObservableCollection
But I want collection to update when button IsChecked value changes

also is there any way to bind function to click method like:

```
Click="{Binding DoWhenClicked}"
```

Now it just results in error I think that is because DoWhenClicked isn't in ItemSource.

Summary:
I want to have Grid of toggle buttons that binds to some sort of list/array/collection of data with label, checked status, enabled status.
When toggle button is checked I want it to reflect in my collection.
Also I want to bind event to Click method so that i can perform operations like disable some Toggle Buttons when other button is checked.
What is good way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you asked several question about Template 10 before, so I supposed that you also used Template 10 here for MVVM pattern.

> binding works when page loads buttons are displayed from ObservableCollection But I want collection to update when button IsChecked value changes

In Template 10 project, if you want to get notified when parameter in the data model (here means your `ButtonClass`), you can derive your class from `BindableBase`. If you check the `BindableBase` class you will find that it has done the work of `INotifyPropertyChanged`, it will be much easier here deriving from `BindableBase` directly rather than implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` by  yourself.

> also is there any way to bind function to click method
>
> Also I want to bind event to Click method so that i can perform operations like disable some Toggle Buttons when other button is checked.

Instead of `Click` event, I personally recommend you to using `Command` in MVVM pattern, and you may want to know which Button is clicked, so you can use `CommandParameter` here. I created a blank template 10 project and here is my sample:

```
<GridView x:Name="gridView" RelativePanel.Below="pageHeader" Margin="16,12,0,0" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.ButtonCollection}">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ToggleButton Width="100" Content="{Binding Label}" IsEnabled="{Binding BEnabled}"
                          IsChecked="{Binding BChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Command="{Binding ToggleBtnClickCommand}"
                          CommandParameter="{Binding Label}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

The `ButtonClass` is like this:

```cs
public class ButtonClass : BindableBase
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public bool BEnabled { get; set; }

    private bool _bChecked;

    public bool BChecked
    {
        get { return _bChecked; }
        set
        {
            _bChecked = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand ToggleBtnClickCommand { get; set; }
}
```

And the `MainPageViewModel`:

```cs
public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<ButtonClass> ButtonCollection;

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        ButtonCollection = new ObservableCollection<ButtonClass>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            ButtonCollection.Add(new ButtonClass
            {
                Label = "TButton " + i,
                BChecked = true,
                BEnabled = true,
                ToggleBtnClickCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(ToggleBtnClicked)
            });
        }
    }

    public void ToggleBtnClicked(string obj)
    {
        var buttonLable = obj;
    }
}
```

In case you need to check my sample, you can find my demo [here](https://github.com/GraceFeng/Binding-To-Button-Template-10).

Comment: Thank you, yes forgot to mention I use Template 10.

Comment: Tried code getting error on compile "Invalid signature for event Click. Events can only be bound to methods that match the event signature or are parameterless"  Works without CommndParameter binding.

Comment: @user5902075, in which line did you get this error? Seems it's the Command's problem, did you use my code or tried using Command in your code?

Comment: Thanks for fast reply fixed problem it was problem with my binding in other place (It was strange that error didn't provide error line, it was empty). Everything works great now. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few concepts that are missing from your code that you need to properly implement for this to work

1. **INotifyPropertyChanged** -> Your ButtonClass class acts as a view model for your view. As such, for values to properly update UI and the other way around you need your class to implement it and all your properties to raise the PropertyChanged event when their values change (in the setter)
2. **2-Way bindings** -> If you want your ButtonClass instance to update when you click the button and you want your button to change state if you change the property in the ButtonClass, your bindings need to be Mode=TwoWay. You might want to explore the new Bindings [{x:Bind}](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension) for better performance
3. **Commands** -> To bind the click event, you need to use the Command property. You would need to create a ICommand implementation, and create a property in your ButtonClass. The use Command property of the Button to bind to that Command.

Essentially, everything I mentioned are components of an MVVM framework, of which there are many out there. Here are some of the more popular ones: [Caliburn](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro), [MVVMCross](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross), [Prism](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism).

There's also a great starter kit for Windows 10 that will definitely kick start your app and contains a lot of this classes already built - [Template10](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10)